# What is the limit of Form recognizer to Compose multiple Custom Models under a single Model

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am not able to find out the correct reference of how much custom models of Form Recognizer I can compose under a single model?. What is the limit for now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/formrecognizer/2.1preview2/compose-custom-models-async/compose-custom-models-async

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. It's not a *here's my numbered list of questions* site. Please review the [help] guidelines to refresh your understanding of how the site works.

Comment: **Question** is **SINGULAR**. One specific question per post that can be answered. **NOT** a numbered list of several **questions**.  If you have multiple questions to ask, you need to create multiple posts to ask them. Please review the site guidelines. Whether I can or will answer is irrelevant - this is about following the guidelines of this site and the way it is designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

With Model Compose, you can compose up to 100 models to a single model ID. When you call Analyze with the composed modelID, Form Recognizer will first classify the form you submitted, choose the best matching model, and then return results for that model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/label-tool?tabs=v2-1

Comment: Hi @Neta. Thank you for your answer. I have one question. What if I have more than 100 different kind of invoices and I want to train more than 100 models. How can I compose those models and what is the best solution to handle this kind of scenario? Thanks